# Android audio recorder initialized failed

Tags: android

I tried to record sound using audiorecorder method like below, it is fine in HTC nexus one android 2.3 but when I tried it on LG and Sony with andoid 4.0 and 4.1 it works once and for next attempt it throws exception in startRecording `java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.` what is wrong?

```
final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 16000;
    int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord
            .getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,
                    RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);
    // Initialize Audio Recorder.
    AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
            RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSizeInBytes);

    audioRecorder.startRecording();
```

Comment: Add some error checking. `getMinBufferSize()` can return `ERROR` or `ERROR_BAD_VALUE`, and `AudioRecord()` can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of not using release(), after stoping the recorder it should released so that you can use recorder for several time.

Answer (score 0):

Different devices support only certain settings for `AudioRecord`. There is a function that lets you to detect which settings does the certain device support.

```
private static int[] mSampleRates = new int[]{44100, 22050, 11025, 8000};

    public AudioRecord findAudioRecord() {
        for (int rate : mSampleRates) {
            for (short audioFormat : new short[]{AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT}) {
                for (short channelConfig : new short[]{AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO}) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting rate " + rate + "Hz, bits: " + audioFormat + ", channel: " + channelConfig);
                        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(rate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                        if (bufferSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                            // check if we can instantiate and have a success
                            AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, rate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                            if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) {
                                return recorder;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, rate + "Exception, keep trying.", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It runns through all combinations of avaliable audio format settings, and returns first matching your device abbilities.
You can modify it alittle and even get all the formats supported by the device.

Comment: @ehsan mozafari the reason might be in that how you release the audioRecorder. Or maibe different devices alow only one AudioREcord initialized with the same settings(just a guess), or like that.

Comment: Still having same problem `Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object` what to do?

Comment: the code you've posted does not show any issues. All other problems are in other parts of code.